# Replicated EC2 instance, SSL cert conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm currently working on upgrading my company's application infrastructure.

We started off with having the basic infrastructure - One EC2 instance which is our web server linked to RDS, MySQL database.

The new infrastructure requires a VPC with 2 Public Subnets with EC2 instances and 2 Private subnets for the DB.

So, here's what I did, I created an image from the existing EC2 instance which has SSL certificate installed in it and it matches with the domain name.

From that image, I launched 2 new AMI and added a load balancer. Now the whole infra has been set up but here's the issue now - after pointing the load balancer's DNS to to the mobile app (via API), there's an error that's coming up,

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match:  !=  OR  OR 
>   03-10 13:41:23.641 29743-30234/example.hr W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:190)
>   03-10 13:41:23.641 29743-30234/example.hr W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:59)

From what I understand is that I'll have to add the load balancer DNS to the root domain (can be done but we cant put down the existing server). Will that work? I can do it but it will take a while for the domain service provider to add it as a CNAME record (Since it is a .hr domain, it's controlled and some records can't be added easily. It will take more than a day for it to be done)

Secondly, if I were to add an SSL cert on the load balancer's level, will it create conflicts with the SSL cert on instance level?

I'm also looking at getting a new domain and to configure on an instance level, will be a nuisance. Is there an alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

Terminating secure connections at the load balancer and using HTTP on the backend may be sufficient for your application. However, if you are developing an application that needs to comply with strict external regulations(EX: HIPPA Cert), you may be required to secure all network connections.

ELB does SSL Offloading/Termination. The load balancer uses the certificate to terminate the connection and then decrypt requests from clients before sending them to the instances and then the instance can use the self-signed certificates.

Ref:

[Elastic Load Balancer SSL Support Options](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-load-balancer-ssl-support-options/)

[Classic ELB HTTPS Listeners](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-https-load-balancers.html)